# Issue with DIV Show/Hide code?

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

The below code allows a div to appear when the user rolls over a link. The issue is, is that the div doesn't disappear when the user rolls off the link. Is there anyway we can make it so that when the user rolls of the link the div disappears, but the user is still able to bring their cursor down and interact with items in the div..... any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
 /* <![CDATA[ */ 
document.getElementsByClassName = function(){ 
    if(arguments.length == 1) 
    arguments[1]='*'; 
  var retnode = []; 
  var myclass = new RegExp('\\b'+arguments[0]+'\\b'); 
  var elem = this.getElementsByTagName(arguments[1]); 
  for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++){ 
    var classes = elem[i].className; 
    if(myclass.test(classes)) 
      retnode.push(elem[i]); 
  }; 
  return retnode; 
}; 
window.onload=function(){ 
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('HoverMe', 'a'); 
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){ 
    x[i].onmouseover=function(){ 
      var m = document.getElementsByClassName('HoverMe', 'a'); 
      var n = document.getElementsByClassName('showMe', 'div'); 
      for(var i = 0; i<m.length; i++){ 
        n[i].style.display = (m[i]==this)?'block':'none'; 
      }; 
    }; 
  }; 
  x = document.getElementsByClassName('showMe','div'); 
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){ 
    x[i].style.display = 'none'; 
  }; 
}; 
/* ]]> */ 
</script> 

</head>

<body>
<a class='HoverMe'>link 1</a><a class='HoverMe'>link 2</a>
<div class='showMe'>stuff 1</div><div class='showMe'>stuff 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `mouseout` function. Add the following code under your `x[i].mouseover` function call:

```
x[i].onmouseout=function(){ 
  var m = document.getElementsByClassName('HoverMe', 'a'); 
  var n = document.getElementsByClassName('showMe', 'div'); 
  for(var i = 0; i<m.length; i++){ 
    n[i].style.display = 'none';
  }; 
};
```

Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/babcN/

Comment: this is awesome! but is there anyway we can make it so that when the user mouses over the div that appears they can interact with the content on that div without it disappearing?